# Why are my Nvidia drivers "installed but not in use"?

Tags: unity, nvidia

Activated but not in use ?  The desktop decided (after install) that I am using a laptop!

Comment: You can verify your current Nvidia driver by opening Nvidia X Server Settings from the Unity Dash.

Comment: We need more details than this. What version of the driver did you install?

Comment: If you are using older video card, then you will probably find answer on this link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/990539

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem before where the nVidia chipset is integrated into the motherboard; a lot of them use the 7xxx series. The only thing I can say is that even with this error, the nVidia chipset ran as expected.

Are you using a separate graphics card (on a PCI-e slot), or is it integrated?